# C++ - why is this code not working when a macro is used?

Tags: c++, macros

When I use the `a->url` inside a macro then it's failing, but when I replace `a->url` and put the string in manually it works. How do I make `a->url` compatible with the macro?

```
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:18:35: error: expected ';' after expression
  cout << MANIFEST_URL(a->url);
```

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define MANIFEST_URL(REPLACE) "https://" REPLACE "/manifest.json";

typedef struct custom {
  char *id;
  string url;  
  custom *next;   
} custom;

int main() {  
  custom *a;
  a = new custom;
  a->url = "www.google.com";  
  cout << MANIFEST_URL(a->url);
  cout << a->url;  
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Think about the macro expansion, would it really be valid if you written it directly instead of as a macro?

Comment: Also remember that preprocessing is a separate step from the actual compilation. The preprocessor knows nothing about your structures or variables.

Comment: Instead of a macro, define a function that uses string concatenation.

Comment: Also, instead of the C style `typedef`, just use C++ `struct custom{ ... };`.

Comment: Why are you using a macro in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Note remove the `;` at the end of the macro definition*)

If you run `g++ -E` you can see the output of the preprocessor.  `#define`s are just text replacement, so when you have

```
MANIFEST_URL(a->url)
```

it will expand to

```
"https://" a->url "/manifest.json"
```

The intention of this macro is obviously to be used with a string literal, and if you do so:

```
MANIFEST_URL("www.google.com")
```

It expands to

```
"https://" "www.google.com" "/manifest.json"
```

adjacent string **literals** are concatenated by the compiler, so the above is equivalent to

```
"https://www.google.com/manifest.json"
```

If you want this to work with `std::string` or c string `char*` identifiers, just define a function to do so:

```
std::string manifest_url(const std::string& replacement) {
    return "https://" + replacement + "/manifest.json";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your macro expands to this:

```
cout << "https://" a->url "/manifest.json";;
```

which is obviously not valid.